# Stack STL with 2 params

Tags: c++, stl, stack

Im implementing a B-tree in C++,I have a stack which saves pairs . my problem is, how i put in this stack  because push only accept 1 argument. thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? Now it seems a simple `stack.push(std::make_pair(first, second));` with `stack` being an `std::stack<std::pair<T1, T2> >` is all you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <utility>

// ...
stack<pair<string,string> > s;
s.push(make_pair("roses", "red"));
```

Answer (score 6):

Use std::pair provided by the standard library.

You can create them with the function [make_pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/make_pair/).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    int myInt = 1;
    string myString("stringVal");

    stack<pair<string, int> > myStack; 
    myStack.push(make_pair(myString, myInt));

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: thanks. I don´t kwon STL. it´s just i need it. thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <stack>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    stack <pair<int,int> > s;
    s.push( make_pair( 1, 2 ) );
    pair <int, int> p = s.top();
    cout << p.first << " " << p.second << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() 
{
    stack <pair<int,int> > s;
    s.push({1,2});
    cout << s.top().first << " " << s.top().second; 
}
```